# Where can I download a development headers of Python 2.7.3 for Windows?

Tags: python, windows, development-environment, header-files

May be my google-fu is ugly, but I can't find a download link to the development headers of Python 2.7.3 for Windows. Does it exist somewhere?

I'm try to build pyinstaller with mingw. Full log of 'waf configure' - [pastebin.com/tJyydGJc](http://pastebin.com/tJyydGJc).

I get the following error:

```
['C:\\MinGW32\\bin\\gcc.exe', '-Wdeclaration-after-statement', '-Werror', '-fno-strict-aliasing', '-IC:\\\\Python27\\\\include', '..\\test.c', '-c', '-o', 'default\\test_1.o'] 
command returned 'Build failed: -> task failed (err #1): \n\t{task: cc test.c -> test_1.o}'Could not find the python development headers
```

Answer (score 1):

By observing my installation, the header files are included in the installer. If you use the standard installation directory, they should be located under 
    c:\Python27\include

For a specific file with just the headers I cannot find either. But there is always the source!

Comment: Hmm. I try to build pyinstaller with mingw. Full log of 'waf configure' - http://pastebin.com/tJyydGJc.

I see the following error: 
['C:\\MinGW32\\bin\\gcc.exe', '-Wdeclaration-after-statement', '-Werror', '-fno-strict-aliasing', '-IC:\\\\Python27\\\\include', '..\\test.c', '-c', '-o', 'default\\test_1.o']
command returned 'Build failed:  -> task failed (err #1): \n\t{task: cc test.c -> test_1.o}'Could not find the python development headers

Comment: @AmigableClarkKant, what 'why'? :)

Comment: Sounds like a pain to build pyinstaller, can you avoid it? Then again, I don't understand really how to use it so...

Comment: Huh, it's just experiment. :) I want try to compare pyinstaller, builded with msvc (default, as i think) and with mingw.